# Add custom tab using Easy Tab in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I installed magento 1.7. By default I saw Easy Tab under Admin > System > Configuration > TEMPLETES-MASTER > Easy Tab

When I enabled Easy Tab GENERAL options to Yes. I got the Easy Tab output as on the link below:
http://questoons.com/ojp/index.php/ring/diamond-ring.html

Now I want to add some custom tabs like CERTIFICATE OF QUALITY AND EXPERTISE, EASY PAYMENT OPTIONS and FREE SHIPPING AND RETURNS. Please guide me, how can I add custom tabs in Easy Tab on Product Details page.

Comment: Dear @andrew, many thanks for replying. I am very new with magento so I do not catch things easily. I followed your link and I went to http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/346507/ link. But after following this thread, I could not activate custom tab. So I request you to please advice me the next step to do. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, when integrating easy tabs in custom theme, you need to copy all easytabs files in your custom theme, add all fields and them adjust theme's tabs.phtml file according to easytab's tabs.phtml file. This is different from case to case, but if you just replace theme's tabs.phtml file with easytab's one, you will ruin all the design but have the functionality.

Hope this helped you.